# Generalization of Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem tells us, that

$ \frac{1}{x \pm i \cdot\epsilon} =\mp i \pi \delta(x) +V.p. \frac{1}{x}$

Is there an analogue of this theorem for some rational positive power $\alpha$ :

$ \frac{1}{(x \pm i \cdot\epsilon)^{\alpha}} =?$

Comment: You mean that $\epsilon \to 0$, $\epsilon >0$, right? Anyway, I suspect that there is no formula like you are looking for.

Comment: For positive integers $a$ you can find what you're looking for by differentiation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727009/is-this-differentiated-form-of-the-sochocki-plemelj-theorem-valid