# Is this 'differentiated' form of the Sochocki-Plemelj theorem valid?

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

For a complex function $f(z)$ continuous and on the real line, and $a, b > 0$ positive real numbers, the [Sochocki-Plemelj theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) says that:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{x \pm i \epsilon} \ = \ \mp i \pi f(0) + \mathscr{P}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx
$$

I am from physics, and often this is written as $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{z \pm i \epsilon} = \mp i \pi \delta(z) + \mathscr{P}\left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$. Naiively, I have differentiated this 'physicist' expression to get $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{(z \pm i \epsilon)^2} = \pm i \pi \delta'(z) + \mathscr{P}\left( \frac{1}{z^2} \right)$, and wondered if the following statement might also hold:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{(x \pm i \epsilon)^{2}} \ = \ \pm i \pi f'(0) + \mathscr{P}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} dx
$$

Obviously this lacks rigour, but is there any chance the above identity might also hold? Maybe there would have to be some extra assumptions about the function $f$?

Comment: First, for the simplest case, tell us what is $\mathscr P \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\;dx$  ?? As I understand it, that principal value does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differentiated form is perfectly valid in the distributional sense, with the limit understood as the distributional limit as well. It says that when you apply the functionals on the lhs to $f$ and take the limit of the resulting numerical sequence, the outcome will be the same as applying the functional on the rhs to $f$.

Interchanging the limit with differentiation is valid as well.

The integral form states exactly the same thing in terms of the action of the functionals on $f$.

$\mathscr P(1/x^2)$ and $\mathscr P \int f(x)/x^2 dx$ are being used as symbolic notations for the functional and its action on $f$:

$$\left( \mathscr P \!\left( \frac 1 {x^2} \right), f \right) =
\left( \mathscr P \!\left( \frac 1 x \right), f' \right) =
\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {f'(x)} x dx = \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {f(x) - f(0) - x f'(0) [-1 < x < 1]} {x^2} dx,$$
which shows why the notation $\mathscr P \int f(x)/x^2 dx$ can be misleading: it's not $\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int f(x)/x^2 dx$ (which is to be expected, $\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int f(x)/x^2 dx$ is not defined for every $f$).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Do you have a reference you could recommend which goes in depth about the above information?

Comment: I am now dealing with a function of the form $\mathscr{P}\left( \frac{1}{(x^2 - y^2)^2} \right)$ under an integral sign with a function $g(x,y)$ and integrated over $x$. I am unsure how this function should be used. $\left( \mathscr{P}\left( \frac{1}{(x^2-y^2)^2} \right), f \right) = \left( \mathscr{P}\left( \frac{1}{x^2-y^2} \right), \partial_{x} f \right) $?

Comment: It seems you're doing it somewhat backwards, first obtaining a formal expression and then trying to assign a meaning to it. If you start with a well-defined functional instead, then all operations, if properly applied, give a well-defined functional. For $(x^2 - y^2)^{-2}$, if you decompose it into partial fractions, you get $(x \pm y)^{-1}$ and $(x \pm y)^{-2}$ terms, which are just shifted versions of $x^{-1}$ and $x^{-2}$, and $(f(x + x_0), \phi) = (f, \phi(x - x_0))$. Kanwal's *Generalized Functions: Theory and Applications* is quite accessible.

Comment: Weirdly, I'm looking at the 3rd edition of Kanwal right now, and I have a suspicion that there is an error precisely in the formula for $x^{-n}$...